# How do computers switch between different processes (is it mainly an OS thing)?

Tags: process, operating-system, task, cpu-architecture, context-switch

Early computers, such as the ENIAC, had to have their program memory (a.k.a. instruction memory) changed manually in order for different programs to run. This would involve changing the tape or punchcard  on which instructions were stored, so that every time a new program was to be run, the tape or punchcard had to be changed.

This limitation of early computers was in part due to the low informational density of rolls of tape compared to modern HDDs, but it was also partly due to the idea (and please correct me if I'm wrong) that each roll of tape was supposed to store only a single program.

In contrast, modern computers can switch between many different programs without having to physically replace ROM. It's easy to switch from one active window to another, or to start running a new program with a few mouse clicks. We now have HDDs and SSDs rather than punchcards and tape, so that we can simply have all the programs we want to run stored on a single SDD and a few HDDs which are connected to our computers all the time. And we never need to change our memory-storage devices until they break.

I hope the above is enough to motivate the following question:

**What are some typical low-level features (w.r.t. hardware and/or software) that enable modern computers to switch between different processes or programs stored in ROM, as opposed to simply treating ROM as a container for single programs as did the computers of yore?**

Comment: Context switching is pretty much pure software, except for modern ISAs that let the kernel handle interrupts on a "kernel stack", separate from the stack that user-space is using.  [What is a context switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/300167) / [The role of hardware vs software in a context switch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18008522).  And proper multi-user OSes need a kernel mode vs. user mode to protect the kernel from user-space (privileged instructions and memory protection, usually via virtual memory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HDD and SSD's are not equivalent to ROM. There is a distinction between a program and a process. a process is a program in execution. Multiple programs are stored in HDD and SDD's. When a program is loaded into RAM it becomes a process. A loader which is part of OS does that. Multiple program can be loaded at the same time in RAM. Context switch is an OS function. Context switch requires not only movement of program or instructions but data as well. A lot of low level features are involved. It is not possible to list all of them. In sort, Yes it is mainly an OS thing.